# Squid's `tls_key_log` does not work as alternative to `SSLKEYLOGFILE` to decrypt TLS traffic

Tags: networking, ssl, squid, wireshark

Following the [instruction](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/TLS) I can successfully descrypt TLS traffic in wireshark while browsing in firefox with `SSLKEYLOGFILE` env variable set and running squid as middle man proxy.

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=$HOME/path/to/keylogfile.txt
firefox
```

> wireshark 4.2.2
> squid 6.6
> macOS 12.6

And I assume squid's [tls_key_log](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/tls_key_log/) could achieve the same purpose for me instead using `SSLKEYLOGFILE` env variable. However, it does not work and nothing can be decrypted in wireshark.

The squid config:

```
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on cert=/my/CA.pem
sslcrtd_program /path/to/squid/6.6/libexec/security_file_certgen  -s /path/to/ssl_db -M 4MB
tls_key_log stdio:/path/to/tls_key.log
```

Looking into `tls_key.log`

```
# 0
CLIENT_RANDOM ..... -
# 1
RSA Session-ID:..... Master-Key:.....
CLIENT_RANDOM ..... .....
# 2 master56
CLIENT_RANDOM ..... -
# 3 master69
RSA Session-ID:..... Master-Key:...........
CLIENT_RANDOM ..... ....
```

Though `CLIENT_RANDOM` keys also appear in ($SSLKEYLOGFILE) `keylogfile.txt` file, `keylogfile.txt` has definitely more key info.

```
LIENT_RANDOM ... ...
CLIENT_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET ... ...
SERVER_HANDSHAKE_TRAFFIC_SECRET ... ...
CLIENT_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 ... ...
SERVER_TRAFFIC_SECRET_0 ... ...
EXPORTER_SECRET ... ...
```

Is it any possible to use squid's `tls_key_log` to properly decrypt TLS traffic in wireshark?

Comment: Are you sure your squid is accepting (and receiving) TLS version 1.3? For 1.2 (and below) only the CLIENT_RANDOM line is needed (I'm not even sure what squid is adding here, but it should be ignored); for 1.3 the key derivation 'schedule' is significantly more complicated and the additional secret values are needed.

Comment: yes, it is TLS 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Just find the same problem here!, after a little bit search, it seems that squid doesnot support logging tls1.3's secerts rightnow. https://lists.squid-cache.org/pipermail/squid-users/2022-January/024424.html